# Modules/Widget System?

Tags: php, module, widget, jquery-widgets

I am making a widget/modules system for my website creation. So far what I have done is made a form post to the main page but when you refresh the main page the widget disappears.

```
<form action="../index.php" method="post">
    <h1>Select a Widget you would like to add:</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="widget" value="MCSS">Minecraft Server Status
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="widget" value="Login">Login
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

And my main page

```
if($POST['widget'] == 'MCSS'){
    include 'widgets/MCSS.php';
}
```

This makes it appear until you refresh the page or go to the site on another PC. How do I make it stay there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[This Post Deleted\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727071/this-post-deleted)

Comment: @Dagon yes. I was trying to get my Code in now. It wouldn't let me add my code last time. I don't know why.

Comment: http is stateless. noting is remembered from the previous request, you have to store any data you want to persistent, and then retrieve it . storage cold be: db or file or session depending on your particular needs

Comment: @Dagon I understand that. But if I do it in database how do I also make it where the user can move around the panel via drag and drop?

Comment: no idea what your asking for anymore

Comment: @Dagon when it displays the module. I want the admin of the site to be able to use a drag and drop to organize their modules. How would I do this?

Comment: with: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: @Dagon well how do I make it where it will move the actual module?